# docker-compose up doesnot create latest tag or how docker versioning really works

Tags: git, docker, docker-image

Situation:

I have cloned existing code from gitlab into my local machine. then I did:

```
docker-compose -f env/docker-compose.base.yml -f env/dev/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

then I have a new image with tag `local`.

then I change something in Dockerfile and then push the code to gitlab. then I delete the image manuelly:

```
docker rmi -f image_hash
```

and then the first command again to rebuild new image:

```
docker-compose -f env/docker-compose.base.yml -f env/dev/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

then I have new image with tag `local`. (instead of `latest`, but why?)

then I want to push the image. I pushed it. then in Amazon ECR, I see image with tag `local´.. :/

I am really confused, how do you guys handle this flow for versioning docker images?

I have one script in staging server that pulls new image with `:latest`.

Comment: Read this: [The misunderstood Docker tag: latest](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375)

Comment: @tgogos thnx, but read it already 3 times, but still can't get the real intuitiv meaning :/

Comment: The `latest` tag is something you have to take care of when you tag your images. Docker doesn't handle it automatically. *It takes a lot of discipline to make that work.* That's why the author of the article proposes not to use it and better prefer tags with versions for your images.

Comment: @tgogos what is version for docker image?

Comment: For example: if your code/software inside an image goes from version `0.1.2` to `0.1.3`, you can `build` different images with equivalent tags. You can visit [hub.docker.com/](https://hub.docker.com/) and see tag examples from images like [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/nginx/tags/), [apache](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/httpd/tags/)...

Comment: @tgogos you mean different image names everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of docker-compose is fundamentally incorrect, unfortunately.

So first things first: Docker Compose is used as a development tool to deploy a stack of services, volumes, networks, etc. so that any individual can come in and spin up the environment necessary to use your application.

That's it's only goal - Yes, sure - it can "build an image" if you have a `build` stanza in your compose file; however it's really only used for then immediately running that image. I guess you **could** build like that, and then rename your image via tagging - but it's not the right process.

Secondly; if you wanted to **only** build the image for your compose files - you want to use `docker-compose build`; which will build given the instructions specified - but will not run it.

Now - to actually answer your question; you want to use the commands `docker build` and `docker tag` to accomplish your task.

Assuming there is a `Dockerfile` in your local path, you would run:

```
docker build -t my_image_name .
```

This will immediately tag it with `latest`. The tag is `completely arbitrary` - it's very similar to a Git tag, except Git tags can't be overwritten without re-writing history. I should also state that **using latest is bad practice**. Why? Because you don't know what you're deploying - if you're always referencing latest, when you go to update your service and it finds a new latest that you didn't expect - you could be in trouble.

Now, `latest` is used as the default - but you could just as easily give it a name right then and there via:

```
docker build -t my_image_name:my_tag .
```

And finally - if you want to rename that tag (Which you could replace `my_tag` with `latest` here if you choose - again, it's arbitrary apart from it being the default. You can also create a completely different image name, if you'd like.

docker tag my_image_name:my_tag my_new_name:latest .

Hopefully this clears things up for you!

Comment: thnx, this was a good explanation. but I still dont know how to solve this situation: I want to have script in my staging and production servers that pull the newest image from registry. how does this work?

Comment: It would depend on what registry you're using, but I don't believe any - ECR included have that. Could be wrong. You can just come up with your own tag that should be the newest, or just name a tag as latest. A tag is a tag. Latest is arbitrary

Comment: so if I have multiple images with the same tag "latest", and if I pull, it will pull the latest image with "latest" tag?

Comment: Images are each in their own repository. That should never be a scenario to begin with

Comment: i dont get what you mean sorry :/. what should I do exactly so that my script pulls the latest image from image registry?

Comment: When you're building your image, tag it with latest, push it up. If you want to pull latest, just `docker pull your_image`